# Plotting the relationship between [graph], [charts], [plot] and [data-visualization]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

From what I can see from the questions under each tag, [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph), [plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot), [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts) and [data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) are currently used fairly interchangeably. The respective tag usage guides are:

> **[graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph)** This "graph" tag refers to a graphic (such as a chart or diagram) which displays the relationship between two or more variables. For the discrete mathematics structure consisting of vertices and edges, use the "graph-theory" tag.
>
> **[plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot)** The graphical representation of a mathematical function or a set of data. There are different kinds of plots, such as line plots, bar plots, or scatter plots.
>
> **[charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts)** Charts are a graphical representation of data, most often in the format of a graph or diagram. Use this tag for questions about using a charting library API.
>
> **[data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization)** Data visualization is the study of the visual representation of data. Maps and charts are the most common types of data visualization, but there are many more.

Are these tags interchangeable? If so, should they be merged? If not, what is the difference in use-case? I can see an argument for [data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) referring to the overall field, while the other tags refer to individual graphs, but other than that, I'm stumped. If the tags indeed have different use-cases, can the tag wikis be improved to make this more clear?

I can't suggest they become synonyms of one another due to each tag already having several other synonyms.